# How to set permissions for specific dataset on Google BigQuery?

Tags: permissions, google-bigquery, dataset

I am trying to set permissions on BigQuery in order to have users being able to see and query tables on one dataset but being able to edit, create and delete tables on another dataset.

I'm not able to figure out how to do this "dataset-level segregation" on the Cloud Platform Console.

Ideal scenario would be:

- Dataset1 - Permissions to see data and query tables
- Dataset2 - Permissions to see, query, create, edit and delete tables.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: it's mindnumbing that something so straightforward and common is so difficult to implement in bq

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**2021 update**:

The old UI (the original answer) has not been available for a long time, but the *new* UI (now called the regular BQ UI) now has this ability.

To change permissions on the new UI, it's a 3 step process:

1. First, you need to open the details of the dataset by clicking the contextual menu `⋮` on the dataset and selecting "Open" (clicking or double-clicking the dataset name will not open the details pane):
   [image: open dataset]
2. On the top bar of the details pane, you can open the `⁺ Sharing` dropdown, and select "Permissions" to reveal the permissions sidebar:
   [image: select dataset permissions]
3. On the open sidebar, click the `⁺ ADD PRINCIPAL` button to open the contextual menu:
   [image: permissions sidebar]
4. On the contextual menu, write the list of emails or Google groups that you want to grant access to, and select the right roles (`roles/bigquery.dataViewer` role for query permissions, `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` role for edit permissions):
   [image: select permissions]

---

**2019 answer**:

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#updating_dataset_access_controls), the permissions are set on a per-dataset basis, so what you want to accomplish is possible.

I can't see how to do that in the new interface (in https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery), but it's quite easy to do so in the classic UI (in https://bigquery.cloud.google.com) by opening the drop-down next to the dataset and click on "Share dataset":

[image]

This will open the sharing panel, where you can select "Can view" for running queries, or "Can edit" to modify the dataset.

In [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#updating_dataset_access_controls) there are additional options, like using the CLI or the API, but I think the simplest way is to use the web UI.

Comment: Share dataset option only available in old UI, not yet released to new UI.

Comment: How does a user with BigQuery Data Viewer access this dataset? Logging in the google cloud console as the user doesn't seem to give any indication on how to access this dataset. User also did not receive any notification/email that they have been given access.

Answer (score 3):

In the Cloud Console you can now set per-user permissions on your dataset:

[image: screenshot of sharing a dataset]

-Michael (BigQuery Product Manager)

Comment: will this be reflected in [Release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes)?

Comment: +Michael did I understand correctly, in order for user to query a table... permission "BigQuery Job User" needs to be at Project level.. Dataset level won't suffice. form what I see..

Comment: Can we do this through the IAM UI in the console?

Answer (score 0):

In order to give users access to a specific dataset on the new UI:

1. Open the dataset and click **Share Dataset** [image: Click Share Dataset button]
2. Give your members the following roles, depending in what level of access you want them to have: [image: Setting the dataset permissions]

**View access** ("*see data and query tables*"):

- BigQuery Data Viewer
- BigQuery User

**Full access** ("*see, query, create, edit and delete tables*"):

- BigQuery Data Editor
- BigQuery User

**Important note:**
Do not give them project level access in your IAM console, unless you want them to have view/edit access to other datasets

Comment: `BigQuery Data Viewer` and `BigQuery User` do not give `bigquery.jobs.create` permissions when applied to a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access on the project level from GCP console or CLI. Once access is given then user can access to all the datasets in the project