# Google Big query does not show project/resource

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a firebase project that is connected to a paid big query account. In Big query i created some specific views for a client. I want to share this view to my client but the client reports that he cannot see the resource or project. I have tested it with another gmail account but i ended up with the same result.
I have googled a lot and tried a lot of solutions (for example: [How to set permissions for specific dataset on Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517521/how-to-set-permissions-for-specific-dataset-on-google-bigquery)) but none of them worked..

- In the BigQuery console i have given permissions by opening the dataset in the explorer pane and hit the blue `Sharing` button at the right of the screen. I tried a lot of different roles but none of them will result in the project showing up on the client . (even the `Owner` role did not work..)
  [image]
- When i login to bigQuery with the e-mail address i have granted access to i do not see the project at the top of my screen. Searching the project on the `Select a project` popup does not give any results.
- I tried to find the datasource by hitting the `+ Add data` button and then `Pin a project` and `Search project`. But no results.
  [image]

First i thought it was a caching issue but after a day it still not appears.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute this query, which gives permission to the Client at the dataset you want to share:

```
GRANT `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer`
ON schema `project_name.dataset_name`
TO "user:mail@mail.com"
```

- Above the option +Add

[image]

- Pin a Project

[image]

- Enter Project Name

[image]

- Enter the project name that was shared.

[image]